# list style as closely as possible to the word of the menu

Tags: css, menuitem

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/zmku8ghk/

HTML

```
<ul id="navi"> 
    <li><a herf="http://google.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a herf="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a herf="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a herf="#">Opc #1</a></li>
    <li><a herf="#">Opc #1</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#navi
{
list-style-type: circle;
}

#navi li { 
    float:left; 
    list-style-position: inside;
}

#navi li a
{
/*text-decoration: none;*/
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
}

#navi li a:hover
{
color: #fff;
background-color: #369;
}
```

As you can see, the circle is outside what covers the padding, I need the circle is as close as possible to the word inside the padding.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style your `<li>` elements, not the `<a>` elements inside them.

Also, `herf` is not an attribute - you're looking for `href`.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/pisaxa/1/edit?html,css,output)</kbd>

```css
#navi {
  list-style-type: circle;
}

#navi li { 
  float:left; 
  list-style-position: inside;
}

#navi li {
  padding: .2em 1em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #036;
}

#navi li:hover {
  background-color: #369;
}

#navi li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navi"> 
  <li><a href="http://google.com">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Opc #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Opc #1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bonus reading material:

- [HTML Attribute Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)